# Integrate WhatsApp with Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, whatsapp

How do I go about integrating WhatsApp into my Salesforce account ?

I found this link online:
https://inteygrate.com/whatsapp-salesforce-integration/

It works, but it has a few drawbacks:

- You cannot use an existing number
- You cannot use WhatsApp both on mobile and on Salesforce
- You can send WhatsApp messages through it, but still have to login to WhatsApp to view replies, so it doesn't keep track of the conversation within Salesforce.
- You run the risk of the number getting blocked, because it uses
  yowsup(https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) library, which is not
  supported by WhatsApp.

Is there anyone who has come across this before and have found a successful solution ?

Comment: Did you ever get started with this?